# Is there a way to factorize large numbers in c++

Tags: c++

I've written the following C++ code to factorize really large numbers efficiently (numbers up to 24997300729).
I have a vector containing 41000 primes approx.( I know having such a large vector isn't a good idea although but couldn't figure a way around this).
This code produces the prime factorization of moderately large numbers in no time but when it comes to numbers such as, 24997300572 the program *stalls*.

Here's the program below with some screenshots of the output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

vector<int> primes = {paste from  

   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nGvtMMQSa9YIDkMW2jgEbJk67P7p54ft/view?usp=sharing
};

void factorize(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return;
    if (find(primes.begin(), primes.end(), n) != primes.end()) {
        cout << n <<" ";            //if n is prime dont'proceed further
        return;
    }

    //obtaining an iterator to the location of prime equal to or just greater than sqrt(n)
    auto s = sqrt(n);
    vector<int>::iterator it = lower_bound(primes.begin(), primes.end(), s);

    if (it == primes.end()) {
        return;                 // if no primes found then the factors are beyond range
    }
    for (auto i = it;i != primes.begin();i--) {
        if (n % *i == 0)
        {
            cout << *i << " ";
            n = n / (*i);
            factorize(n);
            return;             // the two consecutive for() loops should never run one after another
        }

    }
    for (auto i = it;i != primes.end();i++) {
        if (n % *i == 0)
        {
            cout << *i << " ";
            n = n / (*i);
            factorize(n);
            return;         // the two consecutive for() loops should never run one after another
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned int n;
    cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 24997300729 ";
    cin >> n;
    if (n > 24997300729) {
        cout << "Number out of range;";
        exit(-1);
    }
    factorize(n);
    return 0;
}
```

This is OK

[image: This is Ok]

But This is NOT!!!

[image: But This is NOT]

I tried using `long long int` and `long double` wherever I could to over come the problem of large numbers, but that didn't help much.

**Any help Would Be Greatly Appreciated**

Comment: Just a comment -- **Finally** we have an algorithm related question that is close to a [mcve], has the test data included in the code, doesn't use that infamous `<bits..>` header, etc.  Congratulations.  You just need to remove the hyperlink, and make `n` equal to the test amount.

Comment: `n` is only an `int`, but you said you tried to set it to `24997300572`, which is outside the range of an `int`.  The `n` should be a 64-bit integer type, i.e. `long long`.  Then you need to change the rest of your code that assumes `n` is 64-bit, for example, the `factorize` function's argument must be changed.

Comment: What's the point of your second loop?

Comment: "41000 primes" is less than 1 MByte, i.e. not a lot memory on most desktops.

Comment: no need to guess (long long int?)  Use int64_t, and know what size your ints are.      "INTMAX_MAX is                  19 chars (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)" and 
"UINTMAX_MAX is               20 chars (18,446,744,073,709,551,615)"  See <cstdint>

Comment: @2785528 but looking up a huge table like that may incur big cache misses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear (at least to me) exactly why you've structured the program the way you have.

You can fully factor a number by only looking for prime factors less than or equal to that number's square root. Any prime factor larger than those pairs with one prime factors smaller than that, so you only have to search for those to find all the prime factors. Any remaining factors can be obtained by simple division, not searching.

I'd probably generate the base of prime numbers on the fly (mostly likely using a sieve). The square root of 24'997'300'729 is (about) 158'105. A quick test shows that even without any work on optimization, a sieve of Eratosthenes will find the primes up to that limit in about 12 milliseconds.

Personally, I'd rather not have a fixed limit on the largest number the user can factor, other than the limit on the size of number we're working with, so if the user enters something close to the limit for a 64-bit number, we find all the primes that fit in 32 bits, and then use those to factor the number. This will obviously be slower than if we don't find as many primes, but a user probably won't be too surprised at the idea that factoring a larger number takes longer than factoring a smaller number.

So, implementing that, we might end up with code something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using Number = unsigned long long;

auto build_base(Number limit) {
    std::vector<bool> sieve(limit / 2, true);

    for (Number i = 3; i < limit; i += 2) {
        if (sieve[i / 2]) {
            for (Number temp = i * i; temp < limit; temp += i)
                if (temp & 1)
                    sieve[temp / 2] = false;
        }
    }
    return sieve;
}

void factor(Number input, std::vector<bool> const &candidates)
{
    while (input % 2 == 0) {
        std::cout << 2 << "\t";
        input /= 2;
    }

    for (Number i = 1; i < candidates.size(); i++) {
        if (candidates[i]) {
            auto candidate = i * 2 + 1;
            while ((input % candidate) == 0) {
                    std::cout << candidate << "\t";
                    input /= candidate;
            }
        }
    }
    if (input != 1)
        std::cout << input;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));

    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: factor <number>\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    auto number = std::stoull(argv[1]);
    auto limit = std::sqrt(number) + 1;
    auto candidates = build_base(limit);

    factor(number, candidates);
}
```

At a high level, the code works like this: we start by finding the primes up to the square root of the number the user entered. Since we want all the primes up to a limit, we use a sieve of Eratosthenes to find them. This builds a vector of bools, in which `vector[n]` will be true if `n` is prime, and false if `n` is composite. It does this starting from 3 (2 is a special case we kind of ignore for now) and crossing off the multiples of three. Then it finds the next number that hasn't been crossed off (which will be five, in this case), and crosses off its multiples. It continues doing that until it reaches the end of the array. To save some space, it leaves all the even numbers out of the array, because (other than that special case for 2) we already know none of them is prime.

Once we have that, we use those prime numbers to find prime factors of the number we want to factor. This proceeds pretty simply: walk through the vector of primes, and test whether each prime number divides evenly into the target number. If it does, print it out, divide it out of the target number, and continue.

At least for me, this seems to work pretty dependably, and is reasonably fast. If we wanted to do a better job of factoring larger numbers, the next big step would be to switch to a segmented sieve. This can improve the speed of the first part of the job by a pretty wide margin, allowing us (for example) to factor anything that'll fit into a 64-bit number in no more than about 10 seconds.

Comment: It would be great if you explain your code a bit, because it works fine but I couldn't understand much of it :-P

Comment: by the way I just realized the code is unreliable:-)

Comment: take for example 172917933876889=168781*43*7*340369  all are primes; but giving it as input yields 1237, 2347,59560351 as the factors;

Comment: This happens because in your code you didn't check the primes beyond sqrt(n) (which I also did in my first attempt, to minimize time) but there are prime factors of n beyond sqrt(n);

So to account for that you have two options:
1. once you have obtained a prime factor _p_ less than sqrt(n) , perform recursive search for (n/p) again and add it to a list of factors(just as I did);

Comment: or else you can search all primes less than n(**Not sqrt(n)**) obtained by your _candidates_ function

Comment: @RyukendoDey: Once it's divided out all the prime factors less than or equal to the square root, what's left is printed out. There can be no more than one prime factor larger than the square root. Doing a quick check, Wolfram Alpha (for one example) also factors 172917933876889 to 1237, 2347,  and 59560351, just like my program does.

Comment: Doing another quick check, 172917933876889/7 gives 24,702,561,982,412.714285714285714286. In other words, no, 7 is not a factor of 172917933876889.

Comment: Seems I missed some digits

Comment: @RyukendoDey: I'm certainly not going to claim the Wolfram Alpha is infallible. But if you want to claim this result is wrong, you need to show either that the factors I gave aren't prime, or that they don't multiply out to the number you gave. I've already shown where the factorization you gave is clearly wrong. As for those numbers not multiplying out correctly--about all I can guess is that apparently calculcator.com has a problem (probably doing simple floating point math, which doesn't suffice for problems like this).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211567/discussion-between-ryukendo-dey-and-jerry-coffin).

Comment: Since you write pretty decent codes, it would be great if you also post a code on bitwise prime sieve; I've checked some sources for that especially https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-sieve/, but the code written there doesn't work quite well, it misses some primes.