# How to find Largest Factor of a Number (other than itself) in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, cmath

I am trying to find largest factor of given number its simple but don't why my code not giving correct output:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int lfactor(int a)
{
    int *p;
    int s=0;
     p=new int[a];
    int lf;
    for(int i=2;i<a;i++)
    {
        if(a%2==0)
        {
           lf=a/2;
           cout<<lf;
           return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(a%i==0)
            {
                
                p[s]=i;
                s++;
            }


        }
        }
        cout<<*max_element(p,p+a);

}

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout<<"Enter Number to calculate largest factor";
    cin>>a;
    lfactor(a);
}
```

this code giving me some random output input it am trying 15689

Comment: The largest factor of any given number is the number itself, so please rephrase your question!

Comment: please explain where I am wrong exactly

Comment: Factors come in pairs, so  as soon as you find the smallest factor (call it f1), divide the number by f1, and the result will be the largest factor. Also, you probably want to check for divisibility by 2 only once, outside the loop. You can also stop looking for factors when you get to the square root of the number. If you reach that point without finding a factor, then the number is prime. Goes back to factors coming in pairs, so every factor larger than the square root has to pair with a factor smaller than the square root.

Comment: For some related code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154767/179910

Answer (score 1):

You are getting "random" output because you never initialize the contents of `p`. What you should be doing is this:

```cpp
int *p = new int[a] {0}; // fill with zeros
```

You also never delete this array, so that's a memory leak. You could use a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` and not have to worry about deleting it at all.

It's also not necessary to create this array at all. Since you are iterating from the lowest to the greatest number, the most recent factor you found will also be the greatest.

```cpp
for(int i = 2; i < a; i++)
{
    if (a % i == 0) {
        lf = i;
        s++;
    }
}
```

There are still more ways to optimize this. For example, you could divide by `i` and start a new loop with fewer iterations if you find that `i` is a factor of `a`.